# How does one invert colors on Ubuntu Mate Desktop

Tags: linux, colors, mate

Replicating Windows 10 magnifier color inverter feature on Ubuntu Mate has been a series of dashed hopes for me.

Here are the things I've tried:

```
xrandr-invert-colors
gnome-shell-extension-invert-color
Universal Access --> Magnus
xrandr (and many options)
xcalib -invert -alter
xcalib -d :0 -invert -alter
xcalib -d :1 -invert -alter
```

etc.

note the following output:

```
x @ubuntu:~/z$ xcalib -d :0 -invert -alter
x@ubuntu:~/z$ xcalib -d :1 -invert -alter
Error - Can't open display :1
x@ubuntu:~/z$
```

So I guess with my MSI Thin laptop lid closed, I am on display 0, so it is perhaps not a multi-screen issue. (I have not tried it on the laptop by itself yet.)

Pretty sure this is not running Wayland (as some of the above solutions do not work on Wayland) based on checking various env variables, etc.

Compiz might be a solution, but not willing to make the switch, yet.

Isn't there a simple X command to do this? If not, is it because something in Mate-Desktop is superceding? If so, is there a way to do it in Mate?

Comment: does MATE not have accessibilty features?? otherwise you can install them from other DEs. Your package manager should handle that. Debian ships with `Xmag` but not sure if that carries downstream

Comment: MATE does have accessibility features, but not one that inverts the full frame buffer (at least as far as I could find).   I don't think Xmag has that feature either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not on Wayland?  I have used `xrandr-invert-colors` reliably until the switch.

I also was growing pretty frustrated with doing this in a reliable way, especially with my transition to Wayland.  Today I experimented briefly (under Wayland) with some of the gamma-based solutions, but what seems to work well for me and works under both X and Wayland is a script, `gnome-gamma-tool.py` available from https://github.com/zb3/gnome-gamma-tool.

Note that you need to specify inverted (`-c -1`) or regular (`-c 1`), as compared to some tools which just flip it regardless of current state.

If you have multiple displays, you can call it from a script on each one, such as the following, `example.sh`, to invert if you put it on your `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-gamma-tool.py -d 0 -y -c $1
gnome-gamma-tool.py -d 1 -y -c $1
gnome-gamma-tool.py -d 2 -y -c $1
```

That would be called as `example.sh -1` or `example.sh 1`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that if/when i get a chance.